# Android Studio - Can't see Java Directory

Tags: android

1. Created new project in Android Studio on the desktop.
2. in the Android view in the Project Explorer all looked normal.
3. Moved the project to a new folder on the desktop and opened it in Studio.
4. Now in the Android view in the project explorer there is no dropdown icon on the Java directory.
5. I have invalidated caches, cleaned the project and probably a couple of other things I have forgotten, still cannot see my source files.

I tried both copy and move using file explorer in win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top-level project in Android Studio should show the absolute path of the directory on your machine.  Look in the Project perspective (not Android perspective).  Like **D:\workspace\myproject**.  Go ahead and navigate into that directory with file explorer on your machine, and make sure that its java sub-directory contains classes!

Comment: Yes, Project shows the correct path.  File explorer shows the Java files.  What is kind of interesting: if I move the project from the desktop to a folder on the desktop, no Java files.  If I then move it back to the desktop, everything is fine!

Comment: @BillTickner  I hope you are not making symbolic paths and moving files that way.  What OS are you on?

Comment: I am using Win7.  Nope, I just used File Explorer and either copied  or moved the project to a folder on the desktop.

Comment: @BillTickner  Why not just close the project in AS and import it fresh again?

Comment: Well, stupid me.  Never thought of doing that!  Thanks Igor!!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue, although @Igor answers fix your issue, it was different for me because the Java files are missing in the file directory. Same as you, I've also followed the same steps from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html and there's nothing special with those steps.

I have resolved the issue by downloading the SDK quck fix in the "Messages Gradle Sync" explorer.

[image]

After that, the java folder will appear to the project explorer. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar issue: I could see my java directory in the Android view, but not in the Project view. I finally managed to fix it by going in the menu: File > Sync Project With Gradle Files.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library project , then you need to add below lines in gradle library level

```
android {
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

and you need to change the word `kotlin` to `java` according to folder name you already have.